# pthread_cond_signal on stack variable not working

Tags: pthreads

I have two threads A and B. thread A should block until signalled from threadB, The pthread_cond_signal doesnt seem to be working:

```
struct TR_EVT
{
    Dest* pQDest ; 
    pthread_cond_t evWait ;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_tr ;
};

DataSet dSet ;

threadA()
{
    TR_EVT TrEvt ;
    dSet->setContext(&TrEvt); 
    pthread_cond_init(&TrEvt.evWait, NULL);
    .
    .
    cout << "Entering Sleep\n" ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    pthread_cond_wait(&TrEvt.evWait, &TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    cout << "Out of Sleep\n" ;
}

threadB()
{
.
.
    TR_EVT * pTrEvt = NULL ;  
    pTrEvt = (TR_EVT *)dSet->getContext() 
    .
    .

    cout << "Signalling...\n"  ; 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(pTrEvt->mutex_tr));
    pthread_cond_signal(&(pTrEvt->evWait); //wake up thread A
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pTrEvt->mutex_tr));
.
.
.
}
```

threadA() never wakes up. What could be the problem ? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that nothing stops `Thread A` from entering the wait after `Thread B` has already signalled the condition variable.  This would have the symptom you describe.

Condition variable must *always* be paired with some condition over shared state (a "predicate") - you can't just use a bare condition variable.  The wait for the condition should then always be done within a loop that checks that condition:

```
while (!condition)
    pthread_cond_wait(...);
```

For example:

```
struct TR_EVT {
    Dest* pQDest;
    pthread_cond_t evWait;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_tr;
    int thread_A_can_run;
};

threadA()
{
    TR_EVT TrEvt ;
    pthread_cond_init(&TrEvt.evWait, NULL);
    TrEvt.thread_A_can_run = 0;
    dSet->setContext(&TrEvt); 

    /* ... */

    cout << "Entering Sleep\n" ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    while (!TrEvt.thread_A_can_run)
        pthread_cond_wait(&TrEvt.evWait, &TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&TrEvt.mutex_tr);
    cout << "Out of Sleep\n" ;
}

threadB()
{
    TR_EVT * pTrEvt = NULL ;  
    pTrEvt = (TR_EVT *)dSet->getContext() 

    /* ... */

    cout << "Signalling...\n"  ; 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(pTrEvt->mutex_tr));
    pTrEvt->thread_A_can_run = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&(pTrEvt->evWait); //wake up thread A
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pTrEvt->mutex_tr));

    /* ... */
}
```

This way, if Thread B gets to the point where it wants to wake up Thread A first, Thread A will see the condition set already and not wait.  The mutex ensures that this is race-free: Thread B can't set the condition in between Thread A checking it and waiting.

Here I have added a simple flag for the condition, but you might be able to use something else as the predicate instead (for example, checking for a pointer to be non-NULL).

The purpose of the signalling the condition variable is to tell the waiting thread that the condition might have changed, and it should re-check it.